# call and display a text file from a php file

Tags: php, file, call

I have the following php file which displays this webpage
[image: Screenshot of displayed webpage]
Everything inside the black box is from a text file called questions.txt, that is called from the php file with the below code:

I wish to call and display (in the same format, like a black bordered box) some introductory text with images and possible iframes like youtube videos) just before the questions.

In the code below I've included it as a comment # ...have tried various things but it hasn't worked.

The file needs to be called and displayed under "Test your Knowledge" and above the start of the questions.

```
<!-- Main
============================================= -->
<section id="code">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="text-align:center;">

        <p></br></br></br></br></p>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 text-left">
            <p></br></br></br></br></p>

            <?php include 'quiz-sidebar.php'; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 text-center">

        <h2 class="section-heading" style="color:black;">Test Your Knowledge : <?php include "content/quiz/". $_GET['quiz'] ."/title.txt"; ?></h2>
        <p></br></p>

        #I want to call and display a txt file here (called introtext.txt), in the same format as below, but just as text

        <div style="border-style: solid; border-radius: 5px; border-width: 5px;">
            <p></p>
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo "quiz-result.php?quiz=".$_GET['quiz']; ?>">

            <?php

                $loadedQuestions = readQuestions("content/quiz/". $_GET['quiz'] ."/questions.txt");

                displayTheQuestions($loadedQuestions);

            ?>

            <input type="submit" name="submitquiz" value="Submit Quiz"/>



            </form>
            <p></p>
        </div>

            <p></br></br></br></br></p>
        </div></div>

    </div>
</section>
```

Can someone please include in my original code an explanation and fix for how to call and display a text file (or another php file) inside this one, in the position desired.

I'd also like to format the text of the questions to make them left-aligned (have posted that in another question)

I have tried various things but they haven't worked:

**1. include('questiontrinket.php')**  (I included it as below) but it just showed up as plain text rather than rendering the file

```
<h2 class="section-heading" style="color:black;">Test Your Knowledge : <?php include "content/quiz/". $_GET['quiz'] ."/title.txt"; ?></h2>
            <p></br></p>

            <?php include('introtext.php') ?>
```

...didn't work

**2. I also tried the following**

```
 <?php
    echo file_get_contents( "introtext.php" ); // get the contents, and echo it out.
    ?>
```

This didn't work either

Comment: Why not call it `introtext.php` and then you can simply do `include('introtext.php')`

Comment: as a complete beginner to php, could you please post that as an answer, inside the existing code so I know where to put it and exactly how. I've tried that as well as <?php
            echo file_get_contents( "questiontrinket.php" ); // get the contents, and echo it out.
            ?> but it came up with an error

Comment: Please see update with the two things I have already tried with no luck unfortunately

Comment: Almost, you just need wrap the code in php tags so `<?php include('introtext.php') ?>`

Comment: To output a txt file inside a PHP `include 'abc.txt';` is enough (including a txt file caches so speed gains, file_get_contents wont cache.) But im surprised why that was not working for you.

Comment: Kindly echo and check the output of each variables the PATH you define is making issue i think. and you are using custom functions can you give us the custom functions? to know whether it works or not? `            <?php

                $loadedQuestions = readQuestions("content/quiz/". $_GET['quiz'] ."/questions.txt");

                displayTheQuestions($loadedQuestions);

            ?>`

Comment: could you please post the answer, I cannot follow what you've written and don't know how to insert this in my code

Comment: I tried <?php include('introtext.php') ?>  ....it doesn't load or do anything at all

Comment: @Ajmal Praveen - the other functions all work fine. I just need to load and display a php or text file ......

Comment: Sry i didn't re written the code just i was mentioned you that you need to check your custom functions. :) but i can see someone replied you a answer as working code. give a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works fine for me

```
<!-- Main
============================================= -->
<section id="code">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="text-align:center;">
        <p><br><br><br><br></p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 text-left">
                <p><br><br><br><br></p>

                <?php include 'quiz-sidebar.php'; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 text-center">

                <h2 class="section-heading" style="color:black;">Test Your Knowledge : <?php include "content/quiz/". $_GET['quiz'] ."/title.txt"; ?></h2>
                <p><br></p>

                <!-- I want to call and display a txt file here (called introtext.txt), in the same format as below, but just as text -->
                <?php include 'introtext.php'; ?>

                <div style="border-style: solid; border-radius: 5px; border-width: 5px;">
                    <p></p>
                    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo "quiz-result.php?quiz=".$_GET['quiz']; ?>">
                        <?php
                        $loadedQuestions = readQuestions("content/quiz/". $_GET['quiz'] ."/questions.txt");
                        displayTheQuestions($loadedQuestions);
                        ?>
                        <input type="submit" name="submitquiz" value="Submit Quiz"/>
                    </form>
                    <p></p>
                </div>

                <p><br><br><br><br></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by render the image. If you want to display an image from a file on your server, you can just add an img tag in your introtext.php file `<img src="path/to/image.png" alt="image" title="image">`. You can do the same thing with an `iframe` if you want to insert a youtube video. Just think of your external file as a php page as itself. You are just separating the code inside another file but the final result is all displayed on the same page.